# Possible Markdown escaping error on iOS

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, ios-app, markdown-rendering

Glancing at [an old answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33504/7412) of mine, I noticed that in one of the two code blocks, `\\` is converted to `\` and the following line break is ignored. In the other, the `\\` is not immediately followed by a newline, and it appears as written.

I believe this differs from what the web interface shows: both of them should actually show up as `\\` (although it's possible the Markdown semantics changed since the answer was written).

```
Example 1 \\
Next line
```

vs.

```
Example 2 \\more stuff
Next line
```

(After posting, I notice the above examples don't behave the same way, perhaps because the lines aren't long enough.)

[image: screenshot]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be iOS specific.  I see the same behavior on desktop.  Also, if I go in to edit the answer, the code block matches the rendered markdown (no line break, one backslash).

Comment: It seemed suspicious that my examples in this question don't exhibit the problem when viewed on iOS.

Comment: Wow, you're right, the source given when starting an edit does match the rendered output. Maybe a bad migration at some point in history?